# Can't set up DNS server with BIND9

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to set up my own DNS server to manage my domain name, but it isn't working. OS is Arch Linux.

[/etc/named.conf](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dMrBBTXd7P/)

[/var/named/aaa.a.bg.zone](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BD2zZmfVgw/)

output of `dig aaa.a.bg`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.8 <<>> aaa.a.bg
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 11028
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;aaa.a.bg.                      IN  A

;; Query time: 1049 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 06 11:03:46 EET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 37
```

EDIT: The problem was that port 53 wasn't opened on the router.

Comment: For testing query the nameserver directly.

Answer (score 3):

1. What do the logs tell you?
2. BIND searches for the zone file in `/var/named/aaa.a.bg.zone` while you say it is in `/var/aaa.a.bg.zone`.
3. You are querying 192.168.1.1 but it is not clear this is the IP address of the authoritative name server that you are trying to set up.
4. Your SOA record mentions `n1.aaa.a.bg` but this A record does not exist. You meant `ns1.aaa.a.bg`.
5. You should have two *different* authoritative name servers. NS1 and NS2 must be two different servers, not two names pointing towards the same server.
6. This record seems incorrect (though not causing an issues, it does not what you expect it does):

```
aaa.a.bg IN     A       87.246.51.10
```

Since it does not end in a dot, it gets the domain appended to it so it becomes `aaa.a.bg.aaa.a.bg.`. Either at a dot or leave it out because the RR above (with the @) already does exactly the same thing.